# I am looking for a 1960's (?) book that descibes a digital document that can be folded and clouds of microscopic razor sharp robots

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a book in the late 1960's that included a description of a document. I think that it was some sort of map, or book with a map, that could be folded and unfolded and the pages could be turned by swiping like the touch screens today.

The book also described clouds of microscopic razor sharp robots that could turn people into bloody puddles in a second.

Comment: Hmm... [The Diamond Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Age) fits that description, except for the release date. But I am sure many others do as well. Do you remember any other details?